# Slow loading of images

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running a [simple application](http://www.anaadyanta.com) on google app engine which uses some images. Apparently it take a long time to download the images resulting in slow loading of the page.

I tried increaseing the `Frontend Instance Class`, but doesnt seem to improve the situation. Does GAE have this problem, or is it just my application?

Comment: The page loads in about 1 second for me. Is there a particular section of the site that seems most impacted?

Comment: Its not about the page Nate, Its the images, eg the background of events popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page loaded just fine for me. Although I have a couple of thoughts here.

First I would audit the page using the Chrome developer tools (Right click->Inspect Element->Audit).

The audit page show you some suggestions on how to improve the page performance. The most important are:

Leverage browser caching: See [Static Cache Expiration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Cache_Expiration)

Serve static content from a cookieless domain: your images should be declared with a [Static File Handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers).

Specify image dimensions: rendering is faster when you set the width and height for images.

Answer (score 0):

For Images to load, you can use get_serving_url and Google will serve the images for you : fast and almost at no cost, because you do not need a handler to server the images. Google the docs for this.

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810823/python-google-app-engine-image-object/13811289#13811289

Comment: But this is for uploading images to app right? Not sure if this is what I want.

Comment: No this for serving static images very fast, which can also be resized at runtime. The idea is with get_serving_url: Google will you serve the images for you. You aks Google to give you an image url, which you can put in your HTML.

Comment: Get serving url is for images stored in blobstore or cloud storage, he is talling about static images. He should be using static file handlers instead, which mean that the content will be served from a specialized server.

Comment: Get Serving url is also for "static" images. And he has a perfomance issue. The High Speed Image Serving is a good option.

Comment: In order to use get_serving_url, you need first to upload the image to either Blobstore or Cloud Storage.