# get_serving_url in Google App Engine fails in Production Caught InvalidBlobKeyError while rendering

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, blobstore

and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I have successfully implemented user uploads in a form. I have also been successful at displaying the uploaded files (images) on my devserver.

However, I cannot get them to be displayed on production.

I am currently using the following filter for images:

```
@register.simple_tag
def media_file_url(file_obj):
    file_location = file_obj.name.split('/')[0]
    #gives just the key
    return get_serving_url(str(file_location))
```

and in the template:

```
 <img class='visual' src='{% media_file_url promotion.image %}' 
    alt='image description' width='70' height='88' />
```

I have tried the above without splitting the file_location.

I have tried a custom url handler as following in views.py:

```
def images(request, resource):
    clean_key = urllib2.unquote(resource)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(get_serving_url(clean_key))
```

All of the above work in dev, but not production.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Comment: why you didn't use MEDIA_URL?

Comment: Have a look at this question about creating and using get_serving_url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810823/python-google-app-engine-image-object

Comment: cathy: I tried that, also worked on dev, not prod.
@voscausa: Django is a bit different - and the link to the docs is the one I was using to try and render this image.
Thanks both for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blob info was stored in the file info of the model.

I was able to get the serving url in my filter as follows:

```
from google.appengine.api import images

...

@register.simple_tag
def media_file_url(file_obj):
    try:
        return images.get_serving_url(file_obj.file.blobstore_info)
    except:
        return None
```